# Writing large blob of unknown size into SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am implementing a stream interface that takes binary data from a stream (e.g. a HTTP download ord Android content:// share) and stores it into a SQLite blob.

Is there a way to use the `sqlite3_blob_open` and `sqlite3_blob_write` interfaces without knowing the end size in advance?

`sqlite3_blob_open` states that:

> Use the sqlite3_blob_bytes() interface to determine the size of the opened blob. The size of a blob may not be changed by this interface. Use the UPDATE SQL command to change the size of a blob.

---

My current code looks like this. Set initial size (1):

```
// set size of attachment
{
    auto stmt = session_->prepare(
                "UPDATE attachments_content "
                "SET content = zeroblob(:size) "
                "WHERE rowid = :rowid");
    stmt.bind(":size", size_);
    stmt.bind(":rowid", rowid);
    stmt.execWithoutResult();
}
```

Get blob handle (2), this is a wrapper around `sqlite3_blob_open`:

```
    auto blob = session_->openBlob("main", "attachments_content",
                                  "content", rowid,
                                  SmartSqlite::Blob::READWRITE);
```

Write a piece of data (3):

```
        blob.write(data.data(), data.size(),
                   progress.bytesProcessed /* offset */);
```

Given that the `blob` object cannot resize the blob, is there any other way to incrementally increase the blob size then receiving more data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only three ways of modifying blobs are

- to use SQL statements, or
- to use the `sqlite3_blob_*()` interface, which cannot resize blobs, or
- to modify the [database file](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) directly.

Due to SQLite's [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), changing the size of a blob can require rewriting the entire row. Therefore, what you want cannot be done efficiently.

I'd consider writing the stream into a temporary file and handling it afterwards.

Comment: Sounds plausible, thanks. But I still have some hope that someone has a workaround for this limitation.